# Know a donation collection service/app appropriate for individuals raising for an event?

Tags: webapp-rec

I work with a non profit organization putting on a marathon-style event where each competitor is raising her own donations, but it's all reaching one goal.

Would like to find a web based system where the donor can select a competitor to donate to and track/compare donations for each individual but all donations funnel into one account. Bonus if it can accept pledge-style donations (ie: $1/mile to be collected after race).

I'm a big fan of [ChipIn](http://www.chipin.com/) but that collects all for one cause and doesn't track an individual's goals/amount raised (in fact the donor can't even specify in a note who they'd like to support).

Answer (score 3):

The one I've seen most used is [JustGiving](http://www.justgiving.com/) - that allows goal tracking etc from what I've seen... but it's UK-only I think.

If you're looking for a US-based site, they have a partner site called [FirstGiving](http://www.firstgiving.com/) which offers the same features.

One key thing about them both is that they track donations and give directly to a charity... so the charity has to be registered on their site.

Comment: JustGiving is pretty much the market leader in the UK, so it's probably worth giving FirstGiving a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have used [Every Day Hero](http://everydayhero.com.au/) in the past.
Reliable in my experience;
Easy to link to FaceBook etc;
Has a goal indicator;
Customisable backgrounds;
Supporters can leave a message or remain anonymous;
emails receipts to supporter's email address for tax deductable donations.

[Example page](http://www.everydayhero.com.au/alisonbray)

Answer (score 0):

[Movember](http://movember.com) has a really good system - looks like it will do 100% of what you want, but alas, does not seem to be clear what they're using, or if it was developed specifically for the one cause.